# How to encrypt an uploaded file before saving to disk after posting to express route, then read it back securely?

Tags: node.js, express, security, encryption

As the question states. I have a process right now where a user can 'post' and upload a file to my express webserver, which I save onto the disk. My issue is anyone who is able to get access to the server can get their hands on the file and look at its contents. Is there I can any way within my express post handler to encrypt/protect the file such that what gets saved onto disk is not readable/accessible by the user though the server.js file can open up the file and 'decrypt' it securely and perform processing on it that is returned to the user? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: let me know if this solve your problem, https://medium.com/@brandonstilson/lets-encrypt-files-with-node-85037bea8c0e

Comment: Do you have a key management in place? Or where do you plan to store the encryption key? If you store it on the server, you're back on square one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the multer package and the inbuilt crypto module to upload files and encrypt them before storing to disk. They can then be decrypted and read back via a get route.

The files will be saved to ./uploads with a name of [originalfile]_encrypted.[ext].

Uploaded files can be retrieved with a GET request to /file/:fileName.

I'm using AES-256-CBC to encrypt the files, but you could select whichever algorithm you wish. Obviously you'd have to change the key and/or iv length.

There are a few enhancements that would make this a better solution, for example making sure the encrypted file names are uniqified.

For example:

```
const express = require("express");
const port = 8080;
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const stream = require("stream");

const CryptoAlgorithm = "aes-256-cbc";

// Obviously keys should not be kept in code, these should be populated with environmental variables or key store
const secret = {
    iv: Buffer.from('efb2da92cff888c9c295dc4ee682789c', 'hex'),
    key: Buffer.from('6245cb9b8dab1c1630bb3283063f963574d612ca6ec60bc8a5d1e07ddd3f7c53', 'hex')
}

app.use(express.static("./public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage });

function encrypt(algorithm, buffer, key, iv) {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(buffer),cipher.final()]);
    return encrypted;
};

function decrypt(algorithm, buffer, key, iv) {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    const decrypted = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(buffer), decipher.final()]);
    return decrypted;
}

function getEncryptedFilePath(filePath) {
    return path.join(path.dirname(filePath), path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath)) + "_encrypted" + path.extname(filePath))
}

function saveEncryptedFile(buffer, filePath, key, iv) {
    const encrypted = encrypt(CryptoAlgorithm, buffer, key, iv);

    filePath = getEncryptedFilePath(filePath);
    if (!fs.existsSync(path.dirname(filePath))) {
        fs.mkdirSync(path.dirname(filePath))
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, encrypted);
}

function getEncryptedFile(filePath, key, iv) {
    filePath = getEncryptedFilePath(filePath);
    const encrypted = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    const buffer = decrypt(CryptoAlgorithm, encrypted, key, iv);
    return buffer;
}

app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"),  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("file upload: ", req.file.originalname);
    saveEncryptedFile(req.file.buffer, path.join("./uploads", req.file.originalname), secret.key, secret.iv);
    res.status(201).json( { status: "ok" });
});

app.get("/file/:fileName", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Getting file:", req.params.fileName);
    const buffer = getEncryptedFile(path.join("./uploads", req.params.fileName), secret.key, secret.iv);
    const readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
    readStream.end(buffer);
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=" + req.params.fileName,
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "Content-Length": buffer.length
    });
    res.end(buffer);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Serving at http://localhost:${port}`);
```